# Context API weird situation

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to make all the Screen components share a context, and so far I'm unsuccessful. The Screens get passed into Modal, then their content props get displayed. How can I make the Screens share a context?

Things start here... not a component!

```
const content1 = (props) => <div>
    one
</div>
const content2 = (props) => <div>
    two
</div>

...

const screens = [
  <Screen
    content={content1}
  />,
  <Screen
    content={content2}
  />
]
```

ContentContext.js

```
import {React, createContext} from 'react';

const ContentContext = createContext({a:'apple'});

export default ContentContext;
```

Screen.js

```
import { React, useContext } from 'react';
import ContentContext from '../context/ContentContext';

export default function Screen(props) { 
  const content = props.content;
  const contentData = useContext(ContentContext);

  // I can't wrap content() in a consumer because it's a return value not a function,
  // and useContext doesn't work either.
  return (
  <>
    {content()}
  </>
  )
}
```

Modal.js

```
...

export default function Modal(props) {
  ...
  const { contentData, setContentData } = useContext(ContentContext);
  ...
  return (
    <ContentContext.Provider value={{a:'aaapl'}}>
      {props.screens.map((Component) => (
        Component
      ))}
    </ContentContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is your question? The four samples you've shared also only appear tangentially related - it's not clear how you expect this to fit together. Please try and create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not passing the right props to your provider. Note that you should wrap all the elements you want to have access to the context with the same provider (you usually wrap the entire app).

Here is a simple example of that:

I create a custom hook that returns the context, which I can call anywhere from inside my app, since the `Provider` wraps all the children.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(
    !!localStorage.getItem('customToken'),
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
  }
  return context;
}
```

Then you would do something like this in your `index.js` file, for example:

```
  <Provider>
      <App/>
  </Provider>
```